# Is it possible to get value from highlighted from bar data in combined bar chart using MPAndroid Chart?

Tags: java, android, charts, mpandroidchart

I want to get value from stacked bar chart in MP Android Chart.

I'm using Combined Chart (`Line` + `StackedBar`) and I have 10 stacked bar in a row. Is it possible to highlight and get value for each stacked bar ?

Comment: Yes, I think that should be possible, but it is probably easier to help you if you could show us what you have tried by providing a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback, and hey, welcome to upvote privileges ;-)